# When I click on Captcha then click on Login it not working

Tags: java, selenium

I have an application, on the login page of an application I have a username, password captcha, and log in. When I fill in username, password and click on captcha it's working fine but when I click on login it not working. Please check the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1qhua85
Page Link: https://sell360d.allomate.solutions/login
My code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 10);
  WebElement username = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("exampleInputEmail_2")));
  username.sendKeys("username");
  
  WebElement password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("exampleInputpwd_2")));
  password.sendKeys("password");
  
  WebElement captcha = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/div/div[1]/app-login-component/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div/re-captcha/div/div/iframe")));
  captcha.click();
  
  WebElement login = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/div/div[1]/app-login-component/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[4]/button")));
  login.click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is captcha is in iframe, and login button is not.

also try to put some hardcoded sleep, cause explicit wait does not seems to be working:

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 10);
  WebElement username = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("exampleInputEmail_2")));
  username.sendKeys("username");
  
  WebElement password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("exampleInputpwd_2")));
  password.sendKeys("password");
  
  WebElement captcha = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/div/div[1]/app-login-component/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div/re-captcha/div/div/iframe")));
  captcha.click();
  
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  
  WebElement login = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn-login')]")));
  login.click();
```

Comment: I already apply driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); but not working

Comment: @Zaman10 :  try above the updated code, it works in my local

Comment: Great ! It's working. can you please share the process of creating xpath as you create for the login button?

Comment: Sure, basically, you xpath is like `//tagname[@attributename='attribute value']`, also wanted only `btn-login` so I have used contains.